# Multiple layouts for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass

I'm creating a UITableView that uses custom UITableViewCell classes. The UITableViewCell uses it's own methods to lay itself out depending on the indexPath and selected index.

Code is as follows:
AgendaView.h
TableViewDelegate Methods

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

EventInfoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"infoCell"];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[EventInfoCell alloc]initWithStyle:0 reuseIdentifier:@"infoCell"];
}

cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
cell.delegate = self;

TimerEvent *event = [_eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
EventInfo *info = [event valueForKey:@"eventInfo"];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"h:mma"];
cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:event.date]];

cell.titleField.text = [info title];

cell.bgImageView.frame = cell.frame;

cell.countdownLabel.text = [self getCountdown:event];

if (_selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
    [cell layoutSelected:YES editing:[tableView isEditing]];

    if ([info location]) 
        cell.locationField.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[info location]];
    else
        cell.locationField.text = @"Location";

    if ([info notes]) 
        cell.notesView.text = [info notes];
    else
        cell.notesView.text = @"Notes";
}else
    [cell layoutSelected:NO editing:NO];

return cell;
}
```

Is this an acceptable way to layout a cell? Or should I create different cell subclasses for the different cell layouts? If it helps, the cell's expand when touched to show more information, which is why I had the subclass handle it's own layouts.

Images: http://tinypic.com/r/2vjpi12/6

The cells information is determined by the TimerEvent/Info assigned during tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: you definitely should not alloc a NSDateFormatter inside the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It's too expensive.

Comment: should i call a method within or have an array of the time data already?

Comment: You could do something like the answer below--for a cell that requires an `NSDateFormatter`, you can have that allocated already as a member variable on each cell instance.. Since you're not allocating new cells each time a row appears (they're reused) that should help.

Comment: Actually I remember `NSDateFormatter` being too slow to use in table cells, even pre-allocated... I had to memoize the date strings for each row to avoid formatting dates during the cellForRow stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should instead create different UITableViewCell subclasses for each type of row. This is a sketch of how I might do it:

```
@interface UITableViewCell (MyTableViewSupport)
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) id value ; // value to display
+(NSString *)identifier ; // reuse identifier for this class
@end

@implementation UITableViewCell (MyTableViewSupport)

+(NSString*)identifier
{
    return NSStringFromClass( self ) ;
}

const char * sValueKey = "TableCellValue";
-(void)setValue:(id)value
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject( self, sValueKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC ) ;
}

-(id)value
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject( self, sValueKey ) ;
}

@end

@interface TableCellA : TableViewCell
@end

@interface TableCellB : TableViewCell
@end

@implementation TableCellA

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    // one type of layout
}

@end

@implementation TableCellB

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    // another type of layout
}

@end
```

Your table view data source (probably your view controller):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id value = [ self _valueForRowAtIndexPath ] ;
    Class cellClass = /// ...look up cell class based on section/row or type of value, etc.

    UITableViewCell * cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellClass.identifier ] ;
    if ( !cell )
    {
        cell = [ [ cellClass alloc ] init ] ;
    }

    cell.value = value ;
    return cell ;
}
```

EDIT: extended explanation of the above:

The first part of the code (the category) on UITableViewCell extends it to provide a `cellIdentifier` class method and a `value` property. Now all instances of UITableViewCell support setting/getting the "value" property, including your subclasses.

Let's say you have to types of row, **Employees** and **Companies**. You would create `EmployeeCell` and `CompanyCell`:

```
@interface EmployeeCell : UITableViewCell

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    // layout code for employee cells
}

-(void)setValue:(id)value
{
    [ super setValue:value ] ;
    // configure the subviews of this employee cell (first name label, last name label, photo, for example) based on `value`
}

@end

@implementation CompanyCell : UITableViewCell

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    // layout code for company cells
}

-(void)setValue:(id)value
{
    [ super setValue:value ] ;

    // configure the subviews of this company cell (company name label, address label, CEO label, for example) based on `value`
}

@end
```

Comment: i'm not sure what the value is for, i added images of the different cells

Comment: use value to mean the object being represented by the cell in your tableview. The concept is: a cell is a visual representation of some model data. For example, if your table view is of address book contacts, you'd set value to the address book entry being displayed by that cell.

Comment: This code was just an example of how I might structure my cell/table view/data source object graph... it's not complete.

Comment: that's what i thought, just wanted to confirm. i'll try it

Comment: I added the getter/setter for `value` just to show how that's done in a category on `UITableViewCell`

Comment: So the idea is to add a category to UITableViewCell; the identifier and value (TimerEvent), then subclass UITableViewCell under the category that I just created. Then when loading the info for the cell, I can use whatever value's that were assigned to populate the fields? Sorry, I'm not quite understanding the first part of code. I understand what it is, but I've never had to apply anything like this before... first app

Comment: yes--the category extends the `UITableViewCell` class to have a class method "identifier" and a read/write property "value". I have edited my answer.

Comment: I don't get the `class cellClass` part, or why you get `UITableViewCell`'s instead of the classes that you subclassed

Comment: Because you don't know what kind of subclass of `UITableViewCell` you will have... But you don't care because all subclasses of `UITableViewCell` support setting *value*, since we added that to `UITableViewCell` via a category...

Comment: great! I think at first this way might seem weird, but in the end I think it's less code and easier to manage.

Comment: the only thing... my one subclass is for an editing cell, which contains `UIButtons`, `UITextFields`, and a `UITextViews`. I have delegate methods to tell my view what needs to be done, and I can't seem to figure out how to make the connection. I definitely agree with your last comment though, it cut my tableView:cellForRowAtIndex: method in half